# How to fetch data from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is firebase data structure.

```
{
  products: {
    product1: {
      id : 1,
      name: "p1",
      brand: "brand1"
    },
    product2: {
      id : 2,
      name: "p2",
      brand: "brand1"
    },
    product3: {
      id : 3,
      name: "p3"
      brand: "brand2"
    }
  },
  brands: {
    brand1: {
      id: 1,
      name: "b1"
    },
    brand2: {
      id: 2,
      name: "b2"
    }
  }
}
```

when I hit the below url, https://awesome.firebaseio-demo.com/products.json, I get this data

```
products: {
  product1: {
    id : 1,
    name: "p1",
    brand: "brand1"
  },
  product2: {
    id : 2,
    name: "p2",
    brand: "brand1"
  },
  product3: {
    id : 3,
    name: "p3"
    brand: "brand2"
  }
}
```

But I want

```
products: {
  product1: {
    id : 1,
    name: "p1",
    bid: 1,
    bname: "b1"  
  },
  product2: {
    id : 2,
    name: "p2",
    bid: 1,
    bname: "b1"

  },
  product3: {
    id : 3,
    name: "p3"
    bid: 2,
    bname: "b2"
  }
}
```

I can store brand information with product itself, but in that case:

1. if I need change brand name b1 to b100, I need to make changes in multiple places (in example 2 places).
2. I can not get the brand list.

What is the best way in firebase to achieve above result for products keeping code duplicate as minimal as possible?

Comment: Joining data has been covered many times before. What have you tried? What technology are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If u want to achieve a separate brand list and also to make it efficient then u have to do it like in your first example and to get information of `brand` ie `brand1` you can call`Query` method to `Brands-node` and query for that required `brand1` node.

i.e

```
Query query=mFirebaseRefBrands.orderByKey().equalTo("brand1").addSingleValueEventLIstener(new ValueEventListener) {...}
```